# java frameworks ( tomcat, jboss ), tcpip, session expiration

Tags: linux, session, timeout, tomcat, jboss

We have in house linux servers from different vendors, so each server has a different distro ( rhel, centos, debian, ubuntu ) and tomcat or jboss.

With some web application,  if the logged user ( windows client ) doesn't "touch" the web pages, after a few minutes her session is "lost".

So she has to redo the application login.

The vendors say that from the web apps view, the session timeout is high ( like 30 or 60 minutes of inactivity ).

- are there specific tomcat / jboss session expiration ?
- could be some tcpip settings, like tcp_keepalive_* or tcp_retries2 ?

We have about 50 offices locations, but to start we are investigating these problems only on the building with the servers : clients and servers are on the same ethernet and same ip network, all copper wired, only a few 100 Mbps switches.

best regards, Sala

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) load-balancer with much shorter session binding than the 30 minues 2) afaik sessions with Tomcat (likely jboss) rely solely on cookies, so as long as the same cookie comes along within the stated 30 minutes, the session should be the same (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14433076), 3) some javascript drops the session intentionally (unlikely). 4) Some users drop their cookies somehow. Given the symptoms with so many different apps, I would look after (1) first.

Comment: Harald, thank you for the suggestions, but no load-balancers here.